# In Highcharts is there a limit to the amount of data that can be analyzed without overflow?

Tags: highcharts

Please take a look at my JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/vm36Ldqq/

The source data is arranged in a `<pre>` HTML block:

```
<pre id="tsp_data">
Date, Employee Contributions, Agency Automatic (1%), Agency Matching (4%)
3/9/2012,23360.46,2386.25,9544.56
3/10/2012,23360.46,2386.25,9544.56
3/11/2012,23360.46,2386.25,9544.56
3/12/2012,23363.66,2386.57,9545.87
3/13/2012,23364.67,2386.68,9546.29
3/14/2012,23365.68,2386.78,9546.7
3/15/2012,23763.65,2413.34,9652.96

...

12/1/2016,56553.73,6132.71,24530.22
12/2/2016,56726.49,6133.12,24531.84
12/3/2016,56726.49,6133.12,24531.84
12/4/2016,56726.49,6133.12,24531.84
</pre>
```

As it is, the chart is completely broken. If we hover the mouse cursor over the series, the tooltip shows the datapoints rounded to 13 decimal places. (To see it better, change the rangeSelector to something like "YTD" or "1y" and then change it back to "ALL") However, if you remove one row (any row) of data from the `<pre>` HTML block and select the "ALL" rangeSelector, everything looks fine. So, I assume the chart is breaking and displaying too many digits due to too many rows of data being interpreted. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you don't need it try setting `dataGrouping` to false (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled). Changing that allowed the chart to show. Also, confirm that your data is in chronological order.

Comment: I thought the purpose of data grouping was to handle large data sets. I have confirmed that my data is in chronological order.

Comment: Data Grouping is to minimize points across large sets - it does some aggregations of the points into groups. So, for example if you have daily values and you are zoomed way out you may see aggregations that show monthly values or weekly (depends on your data and settings). I would see if there is some wonky data set that is causing grouping to miscalculate.